# Spliting a string in c++, getting one integer and one string value out of it

Tags: c++

I have a string which is having student roll number in it and its name like `[33 john smith]`. I need to get the value of roll number in a variable `int id;` and rest of string `"john smith"` in `string name;`

Can you please help me to get this information from `string data = "33 john smith";` into `int id=33;` and `string name ="john smith";`?

Comment: Why did you tag 3 languages ? Yes, it's doable but please show us what you have tried and the problem facing in it.

Comment: If you need a C++ answer, why did you tag this C and *Java* ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you want to do it in `C/C++` or `Java`? Please update your tags accordingly?

Comment: Do you know **any** of these languages? It's very basic programming and (if necessary) can be done without regular expressions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

Comment: You tag with [c], [c++], and [java], but then show what appears to be [objective-c] in the body. WUT

Comment: @ShahjahanKK SO is not the right place to get code handed to you. Please show some effort in solving this problem yourself, and ask for help if you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use `std::stringstream` to archive what you want:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string s("33 john smith");
std::stringstream ss(s);

int id;  
std::string first_name, surname;
ss >> id >> first_name >> surname;
std::string data = first_name + " " + surname;
```